# Time-travel in a Managed Table with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

In the [databricks spec](https://docs.databricks.com/lakehouse/data-objects.html#what-is-a-table) it is stated:

> all tables created in Databricks are Delta tables, by default.

I create a table with

```
df.write.saveAsTable("table_name")
```

With the sql api I can `time-travel`:

```
%sql
SELECT * FROM table_name VERSION AS OF 0
```

How can I now `time-travel` with python?
I search for something like

```
spark.table("mytab2").versionAsOf(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way:

```py
spark.table("mytab2@v3")  # as of version
```

or

```py
spark.table("mytab2@20221012093243000")  # as of timestamp
```

Reference: [Table batch read and writes / @ syntax](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html#-syntax). On the same page there's also an option for DataFrameReader API, although for this you need to provide explicit DBFS path to Delta table, so it's a bit less convenient.

Comment: or you can use `.option` to specify version or timestamp

Answer (score 1):

This syntax also works:

```py
spark.read.format("delta").option("versionAsOf", "0").table("mytab2")
```